# Store each character of a String in a list

Tags: python, string

I have a list object of Strings as given below:

```
s = ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']
```

I want to store the individual characters as a list of list items separately as below:

```
output = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I'],['J','K','L']]
```

I know I can extract the individual items using their indexes. But am not able to store them in the above given manner. Could someone please help me out..!

Comment: What do you mean by not beeing able to store them?

Comment: Store them in the sense store them in the format as given by me...I mean in the form of list of lists..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a list comprehension:

```
In [24]: s = ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']

In [25]: lis=[list(x) for x in s]

In [26]: lis
Out[26]: [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K', 'L']]
```

or use `map()`:

```
In [27]: lis1=map(list,s)

In [28]: lis1
Out[28]: [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K', 'L']]
```

Comment: I am able to get the list as desired from the first method that you have mentioned:   

for x in s:
list(x)

o/p = ['A', 'B', 'C']
      ['D', 'E', 'F']
      ['G', 'H', 'I']
      ['J', 'K', 'L']

But am not sure of how the result itself can be stored as a list...i.e in the format:
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K', 'L']]

Also am not sure how the map works..Could you please elaborate a bit more??Sorry..I am new to this..

Comment: @sid if you're on python 3.x then use `list(map(list,s))`, as in python 3.x map returns a map object. And [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it worked for you.

Comment: @Sid just use `lis=[list(x) for x in s]`, and now `lis` stores your new list.(see the updated answer)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a `list` from a `str`:

```
output = map(list, s)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I dont get it how mapping helps to get the format that i have mentioned..!! I am sorry, but I am new to Python programming..!!

Comment: @Sid I guess your question is already answered, but `map` applies a function (`list` in this case) to all elements of iterable (`s`). In Python 2 the result is returned as a list, in Python 3 you can wrap it in another call of `list`.